# How do I enforce shared library loading on priority in weblogic

Tags: shared-libraries, weblogic

I have multiple war files using the same shared library such as Spring and some internal libraries. I want to make sure my shared library is given priority instead of versions provided by Weblogic. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I have doubts about "prefer application packages" and "prefer application classes" if I set that to "true", will that cover the shared library references war file is making?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the prefer-application-packages element in the container-descriptor of your weblogic deployment descriptor should do the trick.

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/wls/WBAPP/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP663